# Programmatically removing an Entity Framework navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to remove some navigation properties from an entity, it would be useful if I could do this in code to save it having to constantly be done in the designer.

I tried adding an interface to a partial class of the entity that peppered the navigation properties with `[NotMapped]` this builds OK but still brings back the properties populated in the entity.

Is there another way to do this? EF 4.1, c#, VS 2010

Comment: you can clear it by .Clear() method

Comment: This still gets it in the first place though. I need to prevent the retrieval.

Comment: If you are using code first you could just not include navigation properties. If you dont want it at all then why not deleting as Ken2K said.

Comment: DB first I'm afraid and I'm stuck with the DB design and structure. I'd rather have the edits made in code so that I don't need to worry about another developer having to make the designer edits when entities are dropped and the model updated from the database.

Answer (score -1):

- In the designer

Just delete the navigation property in the designer (select it then simply click "del" on your keyboard), it won't remove the association between your entities, but there won't be any navigation property anymore.

- By editing the code generation template

If EF added a T4 template in your solution that generates the entities from the Entity Model, edit the T4 template to remove the navigation property code generation.

Comment: Was hoping for a solution in code so that I don't need to edit the designer. I would like to avoid creating a custom T4 template if possible.